# Sine ploting python

Tags: python, matplotlib

How to get one graph which consist of two different sinusoidal waves? I wrote this code but it makes two separate waves..

```
Fs = 1000
f = 2
sample = 1000
sample_rate= 0.1
x = np.arange(sample)
noise = 0.0003*np.asarray(random.sample(range(0,1000),sample))
y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * f * x / Fs)+noise
f1 = 10
x1 = np.arange(sample)
y1 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * f1 * x / Fs)+noise

plt.plot(x, y, x1, y1)
plt.xlabel('Time(s)')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude(V)')
plt.show()
```

I got this

[image]

but I need to get this one

[image]

Comment: Your question has little to do with computing -- it has more to do with the mathematics of the function you are trying to plot.

Comment: Your second plot shows 2 sinusoids with different frequency and amplitude plotted using the same color. This can be done. But your plot also has a spike at x=0.5 - you would need to define it. Otherwise it's hard to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the "spike" joining the two different signals, this looks more like what you're looking for:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rng = np.random.default_rng()

Fs = 1000


def generate_noisy_signal(*, length, f, noise_amp=0):
    x = np.arange(length)
    noise = noise_amp * rng.random(length)
    return np.sin(2 * np.pi * f * x / Fs) + noise


signal1 = generate_noisy_signal(length=1000, f=2, noise_amp=0.3)
signal2 = generate_noisy_signal(length=1000, f=10, noise_amp=0.3) + 1.5

signal = np.concatenate([signal1, signal2])
plt.plot(signal)
plt.xlabel("Time(s)")
plt.ylabel("Amplitude(V)")
plt.show()
```

[image]